# multiple specific ips to alternate domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ip

I am NOOB. I am attempting to redirect specific IP addresses using htaccess to a different domain. Those ip addresses are of people copying what I type to describe stuff and  put it on their site within a few hours. I want them to just see static site B while everyone else sees dynamic site A.
The code below is redirecting to cat.com which I used earlier as a test to redirect, which seemed to be working. But then I changed it to dog.com but but it is still redirecting me to cat.com. I had put a # symbol in front of the old rewriterule so it should not be in play anymore. I also checked the redirects in cpanel. This is a subdomain I am working with, not the main domain on the account. This htaccess file added only 68.14.155.149 to the redirects section nothing else.

```
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
# -- MOD: Forbid Cross Site Scripting in query
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(allow_url_include|auto_prepend_file).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
# -- END MOD: Forbid Cross Site Scripting in query
deny from 180.76.5.0/24
deny from 198.23.76.220

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^38\.100\.121\.65$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^206\.141\.173\.244$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^68\.14\.15\0.24$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dog.com/$1 [L,R=301]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.cat.com/$1 [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine  on
  RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^About\-us\.php$ About\-Me\.php [R=301,NE,QSA,L]
</IfModule>
#RVS END REDIRECT PAGE
```

Comment: Are you clearing your browser cache after each test?  Browsers aggressively cache 301 redirects.

Comment: What exactly are those ip addresses? What are you trying to redirect? You need to use [OR], right now it is requiring HTTP_HOST to be all of those addresses (an impossibility).

Comment: Yes, but are you trying to redirect based on client ip? For that you need `REMOTE_ADDR`, not `HTTP_HOST`.

Comment: Thanks, I made the changes an you recommended and it appears to be working. It is hard to go against a team of 20 with budget of 100k that is pulled out of black hat. While my hat is clean but empty.